Kubernetes Redis Cluster with persistent node and local storage
I have a requirement to set up a Redis cluster on Kubernetes, and I'm not sure which kinds of Kubernetes specification are best for my use case. I have some very specific requirements that don't necessarily neatly fit the patterns as I understand them, but perhaps I just don't understand well enough.
There will be six nodes, three master and three replica. The cluster will be bound to six particular nodes. These six nodes will each have storage mounted locally on the machine, let's say 100GB each at /data. Each Redis node will be bound to a particular node and always use the same local storage.
I need the /data to be available as a persistent volume in the pod container no matter how many times the Redis pod instance is rescheduled. It always needs to go to the same node with the same local storage volume.
I read the StatefulSet documentation, and it seems to interpret the "stable storage" concept differently. StatefulSets sound like they will deploy to whichever node, then mount the persistent storage for the associated claim. That's not what I want. I just want it to go to the node with the persistent local storage it's already using.
I feel like it will work with node labels and a range loop in a Deployment (and a toleration for the Redis-only taint). That way, I can use the nodeSelector and a label to put the deployment where I want it. I can also use the label to put the PersistentVolume where I want it. So the node, volume and deployment will always match. In this scenario, I would use hostPort on the deployment so that the Lettuce Redis client can discover the cluster state by nodeIP/port.
In this example, the node labels would look like this:
redis-cluster:redis-node-01
etc

And the values.yaml would have a structure like this, where nodes is the thing that would be range-looped over:
nodes:
  - name: redis-node-01
  ...

I'm not sure if that Deployment looping concept is a best practice though. I'm also not sure if it would work with a StatefulSet (with 6 replicas) and headless service, either. I never want or need volume to be re-mounted, so I'm wary of the stable storage concept.
Please share any thoughts you have.
